# How to use LISTEN/NOTIFY with ECPG

Tags: c, postgresql, ingres, ecpg

I'm trying out ECPG for work as we plan to switch from Ingres to Postgres. We have multiple C applications that uses DBEVENTs from the database to trigger different actions.

Now I want to use the Postgres function LISTEN to subscribe to events from the database. And I don't know how to use it.

I understand that I can use the LISTEN function to subscribe to a specific channel from the database, but I can't find any explanation on how to actually catch the information and use it in C.

```
EXEC SQL CONNECT TO :dbname USER postgres;

EXEC SQL LISTEN listener;

for(;;) {
    //How do I catch when something happen here and print or save it?
}
```

If it's not possible with ECPG, is there another way to accomplish this in C?

Comment: This isn't something I've used myself but I found an example program about listening for notifications within a C program. Is example 13-2 from this page any use?: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/libpq-example.html

Comment: It's not ECPG but I guess it would work as a plan B. Would require a lot more work than a ecpg solution would.